# file already in use FFmpeg

Tags: java, ffmpeg, server

I am running a server that stores video files. When the file is uploaded I run the method below to compress it:

```
private void compressVideo(String fileName) throws IOException
{
     String cmd[] = {"location to my ffmpeg.exe","-y", "-i", 
                            "location to my inputfile"+fileName,"-vcodec","libx264","-crf","20",
                            "location to my output file"+fileName};
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

}
```

It works fine if my output fileName is different from input fileName.

But when I run the program with the same names, FFmpeg clearly starts the process but it is not ended (after that I can't open the overwritten file, it tells me that file is in use by FFmpeg).

There is no error followed in the console.

I have tried doing the same thing without running the server and it worked.

As I am the beginner, I would like to know if I made any mistakes?
Any ideas how can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FFmpeg cannot edit files in-place! Output file has to be different than input.

Comment: I have tried runnign the same code not on the server and it worked. "-y" in the command stands for yes to ovverride. Am i missing something?

Comment: FFmpeg will not block the operation, although this will be patched soon to abort it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help!